# Building wheels for torch_sparse in Colab takes forever

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, sparse-matrix, torch

I am trying to run the following on Google Colab :
`!pip install torch_sparse`

At first, it seems to be working fine:

```
Collecting torch_sparse
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/86/699eb78ea7ce259da7f9953858ec2a064e4e5f5e6bf7de53aa6c8bb8b9a8/torch_sparse-0.6.9.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from torch_sparse) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scipy->torch_sparse) (1.19.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: torch-sparse
```

But from here it just keeps running forever, without outputting any error message, and the wheels never get built.

My Colab environment is hosted and uses a GPU accelerator. I can also install torch and initialize cuda beforehand, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 18):

Putting together all the previous answers, here is the snippet that should work whatever runtime of colabs

```
import torch

!pip uninstall torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-geometric torch-cluster  --y
!pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html
!pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html
!pip install torch-cluster -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html
!pip install git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric.git
```

Comment: It worked for me! And took just a minute.

Answer (score 13):

The installation actually got completed after 30 minutes to 1 hour (I don't have the exact timing). However, when trying to import torch_sparse I had the issue described here : [PyTorch Geometric CUDA installation issues on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236134/pytorch-geometric-cuda-installation-issues-on-google-colab)

I tried applying the most popular answer, but since it seems to be obsolete I updated it to the following :

```
!pip install torch-geometric \
  torch-sparse \
  torch-scatter \
  torch-cluster \
  -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.8.0+cu101.html
```

This installation worked just fine and took only a few seconds. So far, it looks like it makes me able to import everything I need from torch_geometric/torch_sparse. I'll tell you if I experience any issue with this later !

Comment: Taking forever to install for me aswell. Above answer didn't work for me.  Any updates to this method?

Answer (score 3):

To ease portability, it is also possible to automatically provide the path to the appropriate url given the available pytorch version:

```py
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
!pip install torch-scatter torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me. The wheels on the build went round and round, round and round. I have written below what worked as of posting date:

1. First find your torch version:

   `import torch print(torch.__version__)`

> 1.10.0+cu111

2. If you're like me and your colab's cuda is not listed in pytorch-geometric's [installation directions](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html), then drawing from the installation method of their [tutorial notebooks](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/colabs.html), use the following:

```
!pip uninstall torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-geometric torch-cluster  
!pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cu111.html
!pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cu111.html
!pip install torch-cluster -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cu111.html
!pip install git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric.git
```

Note: You can use `https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html` to replace above

```
import torch

!echo https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html
```

> [https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{1.10.0+cu111}.html](https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-%7B1.10.0+cu111%7D.html)

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the previous answer, Matthias Fey suggested the following approach for downloading the dependencies in colab :

```
!pip install -q torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.9.0+cu111.html
!pip install -q torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.9.0+cu111.html
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric.git
```

This [Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1h3-vJGRVloF5zStxL5I0rSy4ZUPNsjy8?usp=sharing) and [Github link](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_sparse/issues/85) may help.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, I had pytorch 2.0.1 with cuda 11.8 on windows.

At PyG installation guide: https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/installation.html, I provided my system specification and got the command:

**pip install torch_scatter torch_sparse torch_cluster torch_spline_conv -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-2.0.0+cu118.html**

This worked just fine